# Using scale() for z transformation in R

Tags: r, scale, transformation

So here is my data frame

```
time    value
1       118.8
2       118.2
3       116.7
4       115.3
5       114.4
.
.
.
1000    113.5
1       113.1
.
.
.
1000    112.1
1       112
.
.
.
1000    113
```

I used `df$value_z <- scale(df$value)` to z-transform all
the datapoints given in the table. This creats a new row with z-transformed values, which works fine.

However, the data is actually a concatenation of about 50 data sources.
For each source I have 1000 values. So in my case it would make
more sense, to actually z-transform all values from one source individually; 50 blocks of 1-1000 each.

So I would need to adjust the command `df$value_z <- scale(df$value)`
to not run through all data together but for each set of 1000 rows.

How do I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you already have grouping column indicating which data source each row comes from? It would make a better example if you made it workable - e.g., 5 rows each from 3 different data sources would fit nicely into the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
# add a grouping variable
df$group = rep(1:50, each = 1000) # assumes 50 blocks of 1000 rows
```

Then use `dplyr` or `data.table` to apply a function by group. Pick your favorite:

```
library(dplyr)
df = df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(value_z = scale(value))

library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, value_z := scale(value), by = group]
```

We can also use `tapply` from base R, but it makes more assumptions about your data and may be less efficient. (It won't work as written if your data isn't already sorted by `group`, the other methods will still work.)

```
df$value_z = unlist(with(df, tapply(X = value, INDEX = group, FUN = scale)))
```

---

Here's a little reproducible example showing you get the same results all three ways:

```
set.seed(47)
df = data.frame(time = rep(1:5, 3), value = rnorm(15))

df$group = rep(1:3, each = 5)

library(dplyr)
df = df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(value_z_dplyr = scale(value))

library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, value_z_dt := scale(value), by = group]

df$value_z_tapply = unlist(with(df, tapply(X = value, INDEX = group, FUN = scale)))

df
#     time       value group value_z_dplyr value_z_dt value_z_tapply
#  1:    1  1.99469634     1     1.6397422  1.6397422      1.6397422
#  2:    2  0.71114251     1     0.1892725  0.1892725      0.1892725
#  3:    3  0.18540528     1    -0.4048326 -0.4048326     -0.4048326
#  4:    4 -0.28176501     1    -0.9327546 -0.9327546     -0.9327546
#  5:    5  0.10877555     1    -0.4914274 -0.4914274     -0.4914274
#  6:    1 -1.08573747     2    -0.5379979 -0.5379979     -0.5379979
#  7:    2 -0.98548216     2    -0.3750263 -0.3750263     -0.3750263
#  8:    3  0.01513086     2     1.2515355  1.2515355      1.2515355
#  9:    4 -0.25204590     2     0.8172223  0.8172223      0.8172223
# 10:    5 -1.46575030     2    -1.1557336 -1.1557336     -1.1557336
# 11:    1 -0.92245624     3    -0.5283725 -0.5283725     -0.5283725
# 12:    2  0.03960243     3     0.4938015  0.4938015      0.4938015
# 13:    3  0.49382018     3     0.9764016  0.9764016      0.9764016
# 14:    4 -1.82822917     3    -1.4907437 -1.4907437     -1.4907437
# 15:    5  0.09147291     3     0.5489132  0.5489132      0.5489132
```